# New CIL target: Debugging information

Tags: debugging, clr, cil, pdb-files, ilasm

I'm working on a new CIL target, and I'm not very sure on how to deal with debugging information.
I'm implementing a PE writer myself - so it's not depending on ilasm . From what I've seen in the ECMA documentation, there's the CILDB debugging format - but it's different from both PDB and Mono's MDB. So it seems that if I want to include debugging information, I'd need to compile with ilasm anyway (and use .line directives).

However, even if I do compile with ilasm, it seems to me that .line directives won't be enough to include enough debugging information for full debugging capabilities - for example, how would the debugger know the mapping between my target's identifiers and local variables?
It seems to me that the best way to deal with that is to only support Mono's open debugging format - which would be a pity.

Does anyone have any resource about this?

Comment: Use the [ISymUnmanagedWriter interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this.  COM skills required.  Or [use CCI](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for your answer. The compiler I'm writing isn't written in .NET, and is cross-platform, so I don't think COM would solve it. As for the CCI project, I'm afraid I couldn't find anything about PDB writing there. Did I miss it?

Comment: If portability is essential (never omit that from a question) then you ought to first have a good look at the likelihood that PDBs are portable.  It is a highly Microsoft specific format.

Comment: You're right. I thought more about resources to follow. In the end, it seems that cecil uses the CCI project you've mentioned, so your answer was right all along! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, I found that Cecil has both PDB and MDB readers/writers at https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/tree/master/symbols . I'll port them, and seems like a good way to deal with them.